# Can i access router query params when defining a route's meta data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue Router and setting the `meta` object field, which is used to set the page title and description.

Right now I set up routes like this:

```
[...
{
   path: '/page1',
   component: Page1Component,
   meta: {
      title: 'Title for page1'
   }
}
...]
```

and then synchronize this with the DOM:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title;
    next();
});
```

One of my routes, I want to use a query string in the title, but I can't pass a function to the `meta` object. Is there a way this can be done, without defining the title in the component?

For example, what I'd want to do:

```
[...
{
   path: '/page1',
   component: Page1Component,
   meta: (route) => {
      title: `dynamic title is ${route.query.param}`
   }
}
...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VueRouter doesn't support setting a route's `meta` property to be a function like you're trying to do.

But you could have your `title` property be able to also be set as a function which takes in your `route` as a param:

```
{
   path: '/page1',
   component: Page1Component,
   meta: {
      title: route => `dynamic title is ${route.query.param}`
   }
}
```

And then add a check in the `beforeEach` hook to set the `document.title` to the returned value of the `title` function, in the cases where it is a function:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const { title } = to.meta;
    document.title = typeof title === 'function' ? title(to) : title;
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the [vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object), the `to` and `from` objects in navigation guards are both route object, like the `$route` variable accessible in the component.

Therefore, you can do this :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.query.param;
    next();
});
```